# Add video(s) to a show's season(s)?

Tags: java, php, javascript, .net, youtube-api

Anybody know if this is available in the YouTube API?  I'm pretty sure you can retrieve feeds for shows, but I'm at a loss as far as how to add a video to a season using the .Net (or any other) APIs.

Basically, everything I do revolves on playlists.  I add vids to playlists, and then use the API to run through each video to update descriptions and tags, add video responses, and I'd like to add those videos to seasons in corresponding shows at the same time.  Huge time-saver to be able to automate that process.

The part I'm missing is how to add videos to a particular season for a show.

Comment: "feeds for shows", you mean a channel? "add a video to a season", you mean adding a video to a playlist? ".Net API", you mean .Net youtube API?

Comment: No, some YouTube accounts can create shows with multiple seasons per show and multiple episodes per season.  Each episode corresponds to a single video.  And yes, I meant .Net YouTube API.

Comment: Are you sure? I have a look around of what you called seasons is actually a feature tab and each season is actually a playlist.

Comment: I'm sure, I think it may be a partner-only feature.  Partners can add shows, movies, trailers, games, etc., which I don't think regular accounts can add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing in the public GData APIs that allow you to modify the metadata for Shows.

Comment: Argh! :(  Oh well, glad I asked.  Thanks.